# Color effect opacity/gradient achieved dynamically with css/scss or js?

Tags: jquery, css, sass

### [image: accordian]

I'm setting about building my own dynamic accordian and I would like each tab to look like the image. For example each could be a heading tag with div children or a list.

The accordian will be dynamic and users can add more tabs at will. The top level will be sibling elements and they will have children that dropdown (also dynamic).

I haven't been able to find a solution to sequentially iterate color over each sibling starting from the first and fade or lighten the color as it iterates?

The idea of building my own accordian is to make it as light as possible so that needs to be considered. Anyone out there who can point me in the right direction?

Edit
Tried to add codepen but it wont let me. See my comments below for the link.

Comment: Ouch. Why the downvotes?

Comment: Didn't downvote, but your question doesn't include your attempted try to solve it

Comment: I just spent nearly an hour looking for anything remotely relevant and turned up nothing. Its a hard search: 'dynamically iterating color over elements??'. Give it a try I will be impressed if you find something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Jquery my approach will be like this:

```
//First start with a string to store the color whitout alpha
var color="rgba(180,125,255,";

function repaint() {
  //Know how many tabs you have and which is the % increment you need
  var all = $('.tab').length,
      total = 10/all;

  //Iterate over all elements and set the new color based on Index
  $('.tab').each(function(i){
    var opacity = (total*(all-i))/10,
        newTone = color+opacity+")";
    $(this).css('background-color',newTone)
  })
}
repaint()
```

#### [Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gmJvYg)

---

You still have many ways to improve this code like simplify the color input to accept HEX and other values.

---

#### Snippet Demo

```js
var color = "rgba(180,125,255,";

function repaint() {
  var all = $('.tab').length,
    total = 10 / all;
  $('.tab').each(function(i) {
    var opacity = (total * (all - i)) / 10,
      newTone = color + opacity + ")";
    $(this).css('background-color', newTone)
  })
}
repaint()

$('button').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('body').append('<div class="tab"></div>')
  repaint()
})
```

```css
.tab {
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Add Tab</button>
<div class="tab"></div>
<div class="tab"></div>
<div class="tab"></div>
```

Comment: This is awesome! The only downside is the set number of tabs as the user can add and remove them from the backend..definatly going to play with this now thx

Comment: Yep check the snippet @JPB play with the button to add more tabs I guess the visual number of shades depends also on the colour you pick

Comment: Just checkout out the pen, its amazing. It seems you can have an infinite number of tabs?

Comment: @JPB Yep the script will calculate the number of steps and set the opacity level

Comment: This line: var opacity = (total*(all-i))/10 is hard to get my head around.

Comment: @JPB `total` is the % increment we need on the alpha channel to get the right gradient from 0 to 1 based on how many tabs are. Then `total*(all-i)` is doing that decrement based on the index of the element and is divided by `10` since alpha chanel value most be between 1 and 0

Comment: Thanks for your help I can have a play now.

Comment: Glad to help you mate @JPB

Comment: Awesome bro.. got exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think, there is a plain (dynamic) css solution...

With JS you could create a start color in hsl, get the amount of lines and in/decrease brightness line per line and add it as style ;)

e.g.

```
var brightness = 100;
var startColor = "hsl(0, 100%," + brightness + "%)";
```

then iterate over your lines and de/increase the brightness + add to your element.

here you can read about hsl and play with it:
https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_hsl.asp

Cheerio :)

Comment: Each line is a sibling html elemt. I will look into your suggestion but I was really looking for a js sass type solution. heres the work in progress http://codepen.io/whispering_jack/pen/yMWoZj

Comment: This looks like the first piece of the puzzle. Any idea how I can get started in iterating it over the elements while decresing the brightness? Im sure there must be a sass / js solution?

Comment: sure its just a first piece, the rest should be kinda easy to implement ;) grab all elements calculate (elementCount / 100) = number of colors you have to create (if you want to go from 100 - 0), then for each iteration set brightness - (elementCount / 100) + hsl has the widest support ;) [here a demo](http://jsbin.com/pomusagawu/edit?html,js,output) + play with the values to get the color range you need ;)

Comment: Stack overflow is where you find good people. Can I ask, did you learn this due to a job you were working on?

Comment: If you freelance tell me, can you pm on this site?

Answer (score 1):

Well it took me a minute to debug my answer so I'm late. But I wanted to share it anyway..

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gfdmzk1n/)

## css

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.accordian li {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: yellow
}
```

## html

```
<ul class="accordian">
  <li class="entry" for="entry in Accordian.entries"><a href="${entry.value}">${entry.key}</a></li>
</ul>
```

## js

```
function addAlphaChannel(e, alpha) {
  const oldBGColor = window.getComputedStyle( $(e)[0] , null).getPropertyValue('background-color')
  let r,g,b;
  [r,g,b] = oldBGColor.match(/\d+/g)
  const newBGColor = `rgba(${r}, ${g}, ${b}, ${alpha})`

  $(e).css({ 'background-color': newBGColor })
}

const Accordian = {
  entries: {
      a: '/a',
    'and b': '/b'
  }
}

const Exposed = { Accordian }

$('[for]').each((idx,e) => {
  let key, collection, carr, template
    [key, collection] = $(e).attr('for').split(' in ')
  carr = collection.split('.')
  collection = carr.reduce((o,i)=>o[i], Exposed)

  template = $(e).html()
  let inner, i, cnt
  cnt = Object.entries(collection).length
  Object.entries(collection).forEach((k, ix) => {
    i = {key:k[0], value:k[1]}
    inner = template
        .replace('${'+key+'.key'+'}', i.key, 'g')
        .replace('${'+key+'.value'+'}', i.value, 'g')
    inner = $(e).clone().html(inner)
    $(inner).appendTo($(e).parent())
      .removeAttr('for')
    addAlphaChannel(inner, (cnt-ix)/cnt)
  })
  $(e).remove()
})
```

Comment: Im here. This looks interesting too. In the first part are you getting the background color from the css as a hex value and converting it to rgba? I've been trying to get hsl to work with the other solution as rgba doesn't have much support.

Comment: you can certainly roll your own for hsl conversion.. or use a lib like [three](https://threejs.org/docs/api/math/Color.html)

Answer (score -1):

Ok, here's the best I've got. If the color is just getting lighter and lighter and lighter, eventually it's going to become white, right? So, your accordion should probably have a limited number of tabs, the last possible tab being a white one.

I would probably create an array of specified shades (from yellow to white) and then iterate through this array each time a new tab is added to find the next color that hasn't been used. I would give you some code, but since I have no clue how you're creating this accordion, I can't do much.

Your best bet is to use Javascript to create new tabs and dynamically add color to them from the array.

Also, here's a link to a super useful website that generates colors and shows a bunch of shades of that color: [Coolors.co](https://coolors.co/)

Good luck!

Comment: Its dynamic there are unlimited table. Heres a link to my work in progress. Static at the moment: http://codepen.io/whispering_jack/pen/yMWoZj

Comment: Well, your tabs will be invisible once the color reaches white. So, perhaps you should rethink your concept?

Comment: Even if I lighten by a couple of percent I will get fifty shades. More than enough. That not gonna be a problem at all.

Comment: Exactly, that's my point. In your first comment, you said it has unlimited tabs. But, now you're saying you only need fifty. I agree with your second comment. Just make an array of those 50 colors and use JS to add and style the tabs.

Comment: ok mate. Just check the pen on the answer I marked correct its great.

Comment: With that pen, you'll notice that, if you click the button enough times, all the tabs bend together like a gradient. Thus, you cannot actually have an infinite number of tabs, because they will all blend together.